# Character encoding for Spanish language and emojis

Tags: json, node.js, encoding, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm creating a telegram bot using nodeJS.

Its multi lingual, and i store the language in json files. So far i have two language  files
english.json and spanish.json

These are the files respectively
https://notey.it/n/MTJxbA
https://notey.it/n/MTJxaw

There are emoji in the language files as well, copy pasted from the telegram client. The Spanish file contains strings that were converted using English.

My editor is notepad++
both files are set to UTF-8 encoding, but when it shows up on telegram some characters go missing and i get question marks. I'm not sure how to tackle this problem, or what i'm doing here. I do not have much experience in file encoding.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks guys.

Comment: please add your code where you are fetching the data from file.